# Seattle to Vancouver - few days trip

Tags: usa, legal, canada, finnish-citizens

We are planning to travel to Seattle (as an EU citizen, we are from Finland and our passports are from here) and stay about 2 weeks. We are also planning to rent a car. Since Vancouver is nearby we thought it might be nice to visit there for a few days.

Is there any problem to do this? What documents would be required for such a trip?

We are from Finland and our passports are from here.

Comment: What is your actual citizenship/passport (not just EU).
Are you asking about documenation for the whole trip, or just the excursion to Canada?

Comment: I'd suggest going via Vancouver Island in one direction. Otherwise, as CMaster says, what bit aren't you sure on? Visas? Taking a hire car from the US to Canada and back? Something else?

Comment: Be sure to ask whether it's okay to take the car into Canada.  In my experience there's no trouble with this, but I'm a US citizen.  Your specific country of citizenship matters with respect to documentation because visa requirements are not identical for all EU countries.

Comment: Finnish nationals can enter both the US and Canada without a visa.  To be on the safe side you may want to print your US I-94 records before traveling to Canada, but you would probably be okay without it. I am posting this as a comment because I have no personal experience with visa waiver crossings on the land border.  I think there's a six-dollar fee going into the US; it might be possible to avoid that by bringing your I-94, but I don't really know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finnish Nationals do not require a visa to enter Canada. They would require an eTA if arriving by air, but that is not your intention. As such you should merely need to present yourselves and your passports and the border and should be allowed to enter (following some degree of questioning by Canadian border guards.)

Equally, returning to the US should not require any additional documentation - I do recall however many years ago as a national of a VWP country being charged a fee to enter the US via land. It feels like there should be some way to avoid this if you are returning, but I'm not clear on the details.

As for the car, you should check with your hire company if:

1. It is permitted under your rental agreeement to take the car to Canada
2. The insurance provided will cover you and the vehicle in Canada

Comment: I did this a few years ago, I'm a British national, arrived in the USA via air using VWP, we did as CMaster suggested checked with our car hire company (Hertz) that going to Canada would be allowed, and ensured it was put on the rental agreement. The only real thing to add is when we came back in the USA they wanted to see our car hire rental agreement so make sure you keep that safe and available at the border crossing. I don't remember there being a fee in either direction, apart from the bridge toll when we entered Canada at Niagara Falls, and we found the border crossing pretty easy both w